# Extending component event handler props in React

Tags: reactjs, properties, event-handling, composition

I'm attempting to extend the default event handler functionality of a component that I'm "subclassing" via composition.

If I have a simple component like this:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {
    doSomething() {
        // I want to do this first...
    }

    render() {
        return <Bar onClick="() => this.doSomething.bind(this)" />
    }
}
```

...and I'm attempting to extend that via composition:

```
export class FancyFoo extends React.Component {
    doSomethingFancy() {
        // ...and do this second
    }

    render() {
        return <Foo onClick="() => this.doSomethingFancy.bind(this)" />
    }
}
```

How can I ensure in `Foo` that `Foo.doSomething` is executed immediately before `SuperFoo.doSomethingFancy` is?  I tried an approach like this:

```
export class Foo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    }

    doSomething() {
        // do the default thing
        console.log('here!');  // <-- never happens

        // if "subclass" provided a callback, call it next
        'function' === typeof this.props.onClick && this.props.onChange.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Bar
                onClick={this.doSomething}
                {...this.props} />
        );
    }
}
```

...but `Foo.doSomething` is never called while `SuperFoo.doSomethingFancy` is.  I'm new to React, and assuming I'm overlooking something obvious.  Thanks

Comment: What does the `FancyFoo` class look like?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by leveraging spread object destructuring in `Foo.render` method:

```
render() {

    // extract FancyFoo's onClick handler
    const {onClick, ...props} = this.props;

    // pass only remaining props to Bar constructor, override onClick
    return (
        <Bar
            onClick={this.doSomething}
            {...props} />
    );
}
```

...and then Foo's `doSomething` works as expected:

```
doSomething() {
    // do the default thing
    // ...

    // this.props. onClick references FancyFoo's implementation 
    'function' === typeof this.props.onClick && this.props.onChange.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Now `Foo.doSomething` is executed followed immediately by `FancyFoo.doSomething`.