# How do I extend an event handler in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-functional-component

Something similar to [Extending component event handler props in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598659/extending-component-event-handler-props-in-react) but for React Native and Functional components.

I want to extend a method using a Higher Order Component

```
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState<InputState>(
      props.disabled === true ? "disabled" : props.value ? "enabled" : "default"
    );
    const onValueChange = useCallback(
      (nextValue: boolean) => {
        if (nextValue !== props.value) {
          setInputState(props.value ? "enabled" : "default")
          props.onValueChange && props.onValueChange(nextValue);
        }
      },
      [setInputState, props.onValueChange, props.value]
    );
```

However when I do this, I get a stack overflow error.  Presumably because the `props.onValueChange` from the original props is replaced and chained up indefinitely.

Just wondering what I should do to prevent it?
I am thinking of having a useMemo/useRef somewhere to store the original method.

Answer (score 0):

I need to store the original value in a `useMemo` so it does not trigger a constant update.  I also modified it so it does not need to do an extra evaluation by defaulting it to `noop` if not present.

```
  function useWrapped({ onValueChange, ...props }: P, ref: Ref<T>): ReactElement<Q> {
    const [inputState, setInputState] = useState<InputState>(
      props.disabled === true ? "disabled" : props.value ? "enabled" : "default"
    );

    // capture and memoize.  Since it's memoized
    // as long as the method ref itself does not change
    // it will retain it's value.
    const originalOnValueChange = useCallback(onValueChange ?? noop, [onValueChange])

    // the augmented is dependent on the `originalOnValueChange`
    const augmentedOnValueChange = useCallback(
      (nextValue: boolean) => {
        setInputState(props.value ? "enabled" : "default")
        originalOnValueChange(nextValue);
      },
      [setInputState, originalOnValueChange, props.value]
    );

...

return <Component onValueChange={augmentedOnValueChange} {...props} />
```